# ArangoDB Web Interface Log doesn't work, [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: arangodb

Just installed ArangoDB on Mac Mojave, works great, but I can't get the Logs Tab in the Web Interface to work.  Get a [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: entries

Comment: Have not run into that error, but I have been running Arango in the Mac using the official docker container that can be downloaded from the docker hub. That may be an option for you if needed.

Comment: ok, I will try to check it out, never used that before.  Thanks